# Python - Convert String date "17 Apr" to Date "17-04-2018"

Tags: python, datetime

I've this string variable:
date_string = "17 Apr"

How can I get this: 17-04-2018?

I'm trying with this

```
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%d %B")
```

But I'm getting:

```
builtins.ValueError: time data '17 Apr' does not match format '%d %B
```

Thanks!

Comment: `%B` is for the full month name (April). Use `%b` for the abbreviation (Apr). Refer to [strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) for a list of `datetime` format specifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `datetime` module.

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
s = "17 Apr"
print(datetime.datetime.strptime("{0} 2018".format(s), "%d %b %Y").strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
```

**Output:**

```
17-04-2018
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/time.html#time.strftime), you should use `%b` (lowercase) for "Locale’s abbreviated month name". `%B` is for "Locale’s full month name".

```
import time
date_string = "17 Apr"
datetime_object = time.strptime(date_string, "%d %b")
print(datetime_object)
```

[Pyfiddle](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/dc99056d-0468-4d99-beab-9efba985bfd1)